# ios UITableViewController Label output is nil

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitableview

I used the following code on a UITableViewController.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [buyer count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    buyerobject = [buyer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *Label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[buyerobject objectForKey:@"text"]];
    Label.text = temp;

    return cell;
}
```

When I print the above "temp" I am getting the output. But nothing is shown in the label inside the cell. 
All the cell identifier and tag value are correctly given.
If someone had a similar problem and found the solution for this kind of errors then please help out.

Comment: You are using a `UITableViewCell`. I think you have to use your own `UITableViewCell` derived class for this to work. This derived class needs to have an `UILabel` instance property, and you have to assign it an `UILabel`component in IB.

Comment: May i know how did you gave the Tag as 10 for label inside cell?

Comment: try changing your label tag number

Comment: you are not adding uilable to table view cell [cell.contantview addsubview:Label]

Comment: I had done a similar program with almost the same code and everything had worked well. The other one i used a UITableView and here i have used UITableViewController. Is there a difference in coding in using the above two??

Comment: No there is no difference in the management of the UITableView. I guess you were subclassing UITableViewCell in your other code according to the code posted. As @D.muralikrishna said, you have to add a label to your cell to be able to find it later.

Comment: try adding [cell.contentView addSubView Label];

Comment: How are you adding the label to the cell? Using IB, or programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the UILabel does not refer to an actual view in the UITableViewCell view hierarchy (you did not add it as a subview of the UITableViewCell). Try to set the label with cell with

```
[cell.textLabel setText:temp];
```

Can you try debugging with a breakpoint where you set the text and print out (po Label) what the label object is?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you should use `cell.textLabel.text=temp;`.
You're also searching for a view with tag 10 inside the cell, but probably you've never set it.